# Using fetched Column value as next parameter for evaluation/comparing in next 'IF' or 'CASE' clause in MYSQL SELECT query

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am trying to create a [Flow Control Function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/flow-control-functions.html) query on one of my mysql database. That can fetch some data based on previously fetched column values, before sharing my current query, I am explaining what i am trying to achieve.

As you can see in the below `SELECT QUERY` the result of first `IF CLAUSE` *lead_id* has been used as a parameter in `WHERE CLAUSE` on third `IF CLAUSE` and that works perfectly, similarly the result of 3rd `IF CLAUSE` *Cont_id* has been used in fourth `IF CLAUSE` as a `WHERE CLAUSE` parameter, and that also works as desired, but when we use these returned values *lead_id* and *Cont_id* of `IF CLAUSES` for comparing a value in either `IF CLAUSE` or `CASE CLAUSE`, it doesn't work, can anyone help how to achieve this by using a different approach?

My query is like this..

```
SELECT *, 
        IF(tte.task_id>0, (SELECT mt.lead_id FROM mt WHERE mt.id=tte.task_id), 'NA') AS lead_id,
        IF(tte.task_id>0, (SELECT mt.assigned_to_staff_id FROM mt WHERE mt.id=tte.task_id), 'NA') AS staff_id,
        IF(tte.task_id>0, (SELECT leads.contact_id FROM leads WHERE leads.id=lead_id),'NA') AS Cont_id,
        IF(tte.task_id>0, (SELECT contacts.Name FROM contacts WHERE contacts.id=Cont_id),'NA') AS PC_Name,
        CASE WHEN tte.task_id>0 THEN (SELECT contacts.Name AS LC_Name FROM contacts WHERE contacts.id=PC_id) ELSE 'NA' END,
FROM tte ORDER BY request_log_time DESC;
```

I want to use returned values *lead_id* and *Cont_id* of `IF CLAUSES` for comparing a value in either `IF CLAUSE` like this:

```
IF(Cont_id>0, (SELECT contacts.Name FROM contacts WHERE contacts.id=Cont_id),'NA') AS PC_Name
```

or `CASE CLAUSE` like this:

```
CASE WHEN Cont_id>0 THEN (SELECT contacts.Name AS LC_Name FROM contacts WHERE contacts.id=Cont_id) ELSE 'NA' END
```

Comment: I think you should separate your query into smaller queries, each achieves one task, instead of combining all in one.

Comment: This would be much easier to answer if you showed us a small sample of the data and what the desired result is.

Comment: @Jerry Its a db of a project/task management system, where there are some 71 tables with datas like clients, staffs, leads, tasks, milestones, tasks assigned under milestones etc, tasks assigned are sometimes lead-dependent, and at times they are non-lead based too, and the *tte* table hold data where staff log their time extensions requests for tasks to admin department, which hold data linked to tasks and not other data, but when populating the *tte* data to admin, they require we should serve client name, incase if its a client-based task, else other info, hope u got the overview of it

Comment: @charlesdk Running separate queries and then merging and processing data with backend programming language, are getting pretty resource hungry, as we have to run queries under while loops, thats why i am trying to achieve this through SQL QUERY if i can

Comment: The Optimizer does not honor the sequential nature that you seem to be depending on.  That's not what SQL is designed for.

Comment: Would a "self-join" help?  Were one `SELECT` is fetching the rows at (id-1) and the other at (id)?  (Caution: auto_increment does not guarantee there are no gaps.)